# If conditional statements in Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using the `_.template()` function of underscorejs together with backbonejs. When using underscore.js v1.3.0, I could use an `if` statement as shown:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_listing_list_item">
    <% if(<%= address_2 %>){%>, <%= address_2 %><%}%>
</script>
```

**Problem:** After updating to v1.3.3, I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in the Javascript console. Has this feature been removed? Removing the `if` code fixes the error. If it's removed, is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `if` statement you've already escaped into interpolation mode, so the `<%=` is an illegal character.

This works when I use it in my browser with 1.3.3

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_listing_list_item">
    <% if(address_2){ %>, <%= address_2 %> <% } %>
</script>
```

Example:

```
var t = _.template('{% if(address_2){ %}, {{ address_2 }} {% } %}')
undefined
t({'address_2': 'test'});
", test "
```

(We use JSP so our template tags are `{% %}`, `{{ }}`, and `{%- %}` instead of the defaults, so excuse my tags)

Answer (score 8):

[tkone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123525/479863) has it right but for a template like you have, you could use the special [`print` function](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to clean up your tags:

> You can also use `print` from within JavaScript code. This is sometimes more convenient than using `<%= ... %>`.
>
> ```
> var compiled = _.template("<% print('Hello ' + epithet); %>");
> compiled({epithet: "stooge"});
> => "Hello stooge."
> ```

So you could cut down on the noise like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_listing_list_item">
    <% if(address_2){ print(', ', address_2) } %>
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UgATZ/

Comment: Had no clue about the `print` function.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: @tkone: You learn all sorts of things by quoting the documentation in answers all the time :)